# Translation of “seine Persönlichkeit zu kennen, hilft dir dabei, diesen Schlüssel zu finden”

Tags: translation, pronoun

> Jeder Mensch hat einen Schlüssel zu seinem Herzen, und seine Persönlichkeit zu kennen, hilft dir dabei, diesen Schlüssel zu finden.

can be translated as:

> Every man has to know a key to his heart and his personality, helps you with that, to find this key...

But who helps you? What is the pronoun of *hilft?*

Comment: If you ask me, it sounds like a Commercial slogan and it should be **Hilf dir dabei..**. Otherwise it seems not to make sense...

Comment: Where did you catch that phrase? It's apparently buggy...

Answer (score 1):

The correct translation is rather

> Everybody has a key to his heart, and knowing his personality helps you to find this key.

I would insert a comma after "Herzen", as there are two full sentences connected via "und", plus another comma after "dabei" for grammar reasons. On the other hand, I'd drop the comma after "kennen". It should read:

> Jeder Mensch hat einen Schlüssel zu seinem Herzen, und seine Persönlichkeit zu kennen hilft dir dabei, diesen Schlüssel zu finden.

Thus, the translation as given above is probably quite obvious.